# How to output Property not included in group by and its count

Tags: c#, linq

what I am trying to achieve here is that I want from that LINQ query to return the list with two poperties: billNo, and number of occurences of the importcode on the same fromDate.

So here we have a billNo 1 and 2 both have the same importcode which appears in two rows on the same date (01/01/2020) thus count is 2.

If it helps to clarify, think of it as import code should only cover one distinct fromDate. If it appears multiple time, I would like to see how many times (count) and which BillNo s are like that.

So expected result for dataset below would be:

| BillNo | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |

I struggle to figure out how to select BillNo if it is not used for grouping.

Thanks a lot for helping.

```
var rows = new List<ImportRow>()
            {
                new ImportRow {billNo= 1, importCode = "one", fromDate = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1)},
                new ImportRow {billNo= 2, importCode = "one", fromDate = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1)},
                new ImportRow {billNo= 3, importCode = "two", fromDate = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1)},
                new ImportRow {billNo= 4, importCode = "two", fromDate = new DateTime(2020, 2, 1)},
                new ImportRow {billNo= 5, importCode = "one", fromDate = new DateTime(2020, 3, 1)}
            };

public class ImportRow : IEnumerable
    {
        public int billNo { get; set; }
        public string importCode { get; set; }
        public DateTime fromDate { get; set; }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }



   var billNosWithCounts = rows.GroupBy(info => new { info.importCode,
     info.fromDate }) 
                             .Select(group => new
                             {                             
                                 FromDate = group.Key.fromDate,
                                 Count = group.Count()                            
                             });
```

Comment: For clarification, you have an object with three properties date, import code, and bill number.  You want to count the items with the same import code if they're on the same date?

Comment: Yes, that's right. To count, and show billno and count . Count is how many records in total with same import code cover the same date.

Comment: So the date is not relevant?  Only the import code?

Comment: No, the date is important.. Sorry I struggle to put this clearly.. I want all the bill numbers which have the same import code as other bills on the same date.

Comment: Maybe think of it as unique constraint on DB, importcode/date must be unique. If not, I would like to see for which bills, and how many times this occurs per import code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join the source onto itself, I believe that will give you the output you are looking for:

```
var result = from r1 in rows
             join r2 in rows 
                on new { r1.importCode, r1.fromDate } equals 
                    new { r2.importCode, r2.fromDate }
             group r1.billNo by r1.billNo into g
             select new
             {
                 BillNo = g.Key,
                 Count = g.Count()
             };
```

Comment: Just tried, working! Thank you kindly sir.

Answer (score 2):

You could potentially achieve what you are looking for by doing the following:

```
public static IDictionary<int, string> Map(this List<Sample> collection)
{
     var kvp = new Dictionary<int, string>();
     var records = collection.GroupBy(value => new { value.Code, value.Date });
     foreach(var record in records)
          foreach(var contents in record)
               kvp.Add(contents.Bill, contents.Count());
}
```

A sample of the object you outlined above:

```
    var collection = new List<Sample>() 
    {
        new Sample() { Bill = 1, Code = "ABC", Date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() },
        new Sample() { Bill = 2, Code = "ABC", Date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() },
        new Sample() { Bill = 3, Code = "ABCD", Date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() },
        new Sample() { Bill = 4, Code = "ABCDE", Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3).ToShortDateString() }
    };
```

In essence, I created a method that will let you pass an object.  It will then group on the import code and the date.  Creating the unique pair you desire.  Then I simply add the newly transformed content into a Dictionary.  You could use Linq to do the full transform, but it might become more difficult to read or understand, so I chose to simplify into basic loops for the transformation.

Comment: Thanks Greg for the effort. I believe the answer from DavidG is just simpler here, so I will go with that. I however like your solution too, maybe useful in the future.

Comment: @JanT Yeah, he did the all in one Linq.  It is a solid answer, use what best suits your requirements.  I'm a proponent of not abusing Linq, that is just my approach- does not work for everyone.  Happy your issue is resolved with two viable answers.