# Problem translating LINQ from C# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have a LINQ query that works as expected in C#. I need to translate it to VB.NET.

[Background here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68746339/how-to-output-property-not-included-in-group-by-and-its-count)

None of the online translators give a version that would work

C# (working)

```
var result = from r1 in rows
                         join r2 in rows
                            on new { r1.MeterIdentifier, r1.Timestamp } equals
                                new { r2.MeterIdentifier, r2.Timestamp }
                         group r1.billNo by r1.billNo into g
                         select new
                         {
                             BillNo = g.Key,
                             Count = g.Count()
                         };
```

VB.NET(translated from above) not working: it returns empty:

```
Dim result = From r1 In rows Join r2 In rows On
                             New With {r1.MeterIdentifier, r1.Timestamp} Equals
                             New With {r2.MeterIdentifier, r2.Timestamp}
                                              Group r1.BillNo By __groupByKey1__ = r1.BillNo Into g = Group
                                              Select New With
                                                    {
                                                        .BillNo = __groupByKey1__,
                                                        .Count = g.Count()
                                                    }

            Dim test = result.ToList() ' list empty
```

Telerik's translator gives a very slightly different code but that is not even compiling.

I am pretty limited with LINQ, can anyone spot if that translations is wrong/how to fix it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What's the compiler error?

Comment: On the query shown here, there is none. When using telerik converter, which gives slightly different code, there is. Should I add that code into answer as well?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question a little bit. Apologies.

Comment: Your query seems messed up - why do you join a dataset to itself? At best if you're joining pk to pk you just doubled the width of it. At worst if there are multiple matching rows you cause a cartesian explosion..

Comment: You can simply remove the Anonymous types equality:  `Dim result = From r1 In rows Join r2 In rows On r1.importCode Equals r2.importCode And r1.fromDate Equals r2.fromDate Group r1.billNo By r1.billNo Into g = Group Select New With {billNo, g.Count()}`

Comment: @CaiusJard The reason why is in the answer if you check the Background Info link. It will probably make more sense then.

Comment: @Jimi, will try once I get back to this. Thanks

Comment: @JanT I'd usually recommend to avoid making a question rely on another question in order for it to make sense (other than the usual path of closing questions as duplicates of another). There's no penalty for copying relevant details into a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the background

> think of it as import code should only cover one distinct fromDate. If it appears multiple time, I would like to see how many times (count) and which BillNo s are like that

I think I'd just group by ImportCode and get those where Min fromDate not equals Max fromDate.. it'd give the bill numbers too

```
data _
  .GroupBy(Function(x) x.ImportCode) _
  .Where(Function(g) g.Select(Function(gg) gg.FromDate).Min() <> g.Select(Function(gg) gg.FromDate).Max())
```

Or with a multiline lambda

```
data _
  .GroupBy(Function(x) x.ImportCode) _
  .Where(Function(g) _
    Dim h = g.Select(Function(gg) gg.FromDate) _
    Return h.Min() <> h.Max() _
  End Function)
```

What you're getting out of this is a bunch of groupings, which is essentially a list A of list B of the original objects.

Make sense? No.. OK

Imagine this is a single list of MeterReading(?) objects like (i've omitted the BillNo...):

```
ImportCode  Date
A           1-Jan
A           1-Jan
A           2-Jan
B           1-Jan
B           2-Jan
B           3-Jan
C           1-Jan
```

After grouping by ImportCode, it becomes a list of list of meterreadings like (JSON flavored rendering):

```
Key            (items list - a bunch of MeterReading)
A              [{A,1-Jan},{A,1-Jan},{A,2-Jan}]
B              [{B,1-Jan},{B,2-Jan},{B,3-Jan}]
C              [{C,1-Jan}]
```

If you were to say `Where(Function(items) ...)` then the code in the `...` in the `Where` is run once per grouped row above - there are 3 rows so the code is called 3 times. A single row is an `items` - it has a `.Key` property (that I don't use) that is the itemcode that was grouped on, and the whole `items` thing itself is a list (ienumerable, to be exact) of the input MeterReading objects that went into the grouping operation, so in other words, `items` is a list of MeterReading that all have the same ImportCode, and there are 3 such lists

If you `Select` the `FromDate` out of each MeterReading in the `items` and call `Max` then you get the max date, same for min. If they're inequal then the `items` list contains some meter readings with different dates - you say they should be the same. For lists headed by item codes A and B, the min date is different to the max date. For the C they're all the same so C disappears from the results and we're down to 2 rows

```
Key            (items list - a bunch of MeterReading)
A              [{A,1-Jan},{A,1-Jan},{A,2-Jan}]
B              [{B,1-Jan},{B,2-Jan},{B,3-Jan}]
```

The output from `Where` is "two rows", each with a full list of all the meter readings and their associated data. You can pull that data in various ways, for example:

```
.Select(Function(meterReadingsList) _
  New With { _
    .DistinctDayCount = meterReadingsList.Select(Function(mr) mr.FromDate).Distinct().Count() _ 'the number of different days this happened on
    .BillNos = meterReadingsList.Select(Function(mr) mr.BillNo).ToArray() _
 } _
End Function)
```

There's also a SelectMany operation in linq that can be used to flatten a List Of List Of Something into a List Of Something(else); kinda like the reverse of the GroupBy done earlier. If you were to SelectMany the meterreadings in those two rows, they'd come back out to a single list like what we started with..

```
ImportCode  Date
A           1-Jan
A           1-Jan
A           2-Jan
B           1-Jan
B           2-Jan
B           3-Jan
```

But from what you say about wanting counts per item code etc it seems like theyre better off staying with their 2D representation

Comment: There are a boatload of other ways of checking if there are more than one date, such as `.Where(Function(g) g.Select(Function(gg) gg.FromDate).Distinct().Skip(1).Any())` - `.Where(Function(g) g.Select(Function(gg) gg.FromDate).Distinct().Count() > 1)` - `.Where(Function(g) Dim h = g.OrderBy(Function(gg) gg.FromDate) Return h.First().FromDate <> h.Last().FromDate)` and so on... MinMax is a reasonable compromise - it could be sped up with a for loop iteration that crawls forwards from index 2, asking if this date <> last date and returning true otherwise returning false afte rthe loop is over

Comment: Thanks, will try and see if this works. Most likely after weekend though.